# A nome da coluna dt_ultimo_acesso não foi encontrado neste ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, jpa, spring, resultset

Estou implantando um método passando um parâmetro id:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/entidadesUsuario/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Usuarios>> buscarEntidadesUsuario(@PathVariable Long id) {


        Collection<Usuarios> entidadesBuscados = uService.buscarUsuarioNasDuasTabelas(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(entidadesBuscados, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

Que busca em uma classe service:

```
 public Collection<Usuarios> buscarUsuarioNasDuasTabelas(Long idUsuLogado) {
        return uRepository.buscarPorUsuarioLogado(idUsuLogado);
    }
```

E depois na classe repository:

```
 @Query(nativeQuery=true, value="SELECT enad.id_entidade,\r\n" + 
            "       enad.id_sistema,\r\n" + 
            "       NULL id_pagina,\r\n" + 
            "       enad.id_usuario,\r\n" + 
            "       1 flag_consultar,\r\n" + 
            "       1 flag_inserir,\r\n" + 
            "       1 flag_editar,\r\n" + 
            "       1 flag_excluir,\r\n" + 
            "       1 flag_imprimir\r\n" + 
            "  FROM glb.entidades_administradores enad\r\n" + 
            " WHERE enad.id_usuario  = :parametroId\r\n" + 
            "UNION\r\n" + 
            "SELECT pepg.id_entidade,\r\n" + 
            "       pags.id_sistema,\r\n" + 
            "       pepg.id_pagina,\r\n" + 
            "       pepg.id_usuario,\r\n" + 
            "       pepg.flag_consultar,\r\n" + 
            "       pepg.flag_inserir,\r\n" + 
            "       pepg.flag_editar,\r\n" + 
            "       pepg.flag_excluir,\r\n" + 
            "       pepg.flag_imprimir\r\n" + 
            "  FROM glb.permissoes_paginas pepg,\r\n" + 
            "       glb.paginas            pags\r\n" + 
            " WHERE pepg.id_pagina   = pags.id_pagina\r\n" + 
            "   AND pepg.id_usuario  = :parametroId")
    public Collection<Usuarios> buscarPorUsuarioLogado(@Param("parametroId") Long idUsuLogado);
```

E então estou tendo este erro:

> ```
> 2017-10-23 09:45:34.025  WARN 7104 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
> 2017-10-23 09:45:34.025 ERROR 7104 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : A nome da coluna dt_ultimo_acesso não foi encontrado neste ResultSet.
> 2017-10-23 09:45:34.038 ERROR 7104 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [SELECT enad.id_entidade,
>        enad.id_sistema,
>        NULL id_pagina,
>        enad.id_usuario,
>        1 flag_consultar,
>        1 flag_inserir,
>        1 flag_editar,
>        1 flag_excluir,
>        1 flag_imprimir
>   FROM glb.entidades_administradores enad
>  WHERE enad.id_usuario  = ?
> UNION
> SELECT pepg.id_entidade,
>        pags.id_sistema,
>        pepg.id_pagina,
>        pepg.id_usuario,
>        pepg.flag_consultar,
>        pepg.flag_inserir,
>        pepg.flag_editar,
>        pepg.flag_excluir,
>        pepg.flag_imprimir
>   FROM glb.permissoes_paginas pepg,
>        glb.paginas            pags
>  WHERE pepg.id_pagina   = pags.id_pagina
>    AND pepg.id_usuario  = ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A nome da coluna dt_ultimo_acesso não foi encontrado neste ResultSet.
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.findColumn(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2727) ~[postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc41.jar:na]
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getTimestamp(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2628) ~[postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc41.jar:na]
>     at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.TimestampTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(TimestampTypeDescriptor.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2790) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1729) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1655) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1544) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
> ```

A questão é que se eu executo o SQL direto no banco de dados ele executa sem erros.

Sei que tem algo a ver com o `alias` mas não sei como resolver....

Classe `Usuarios`:

```java
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name="usuarios" , schema="glb")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "idUsuario", scope= Usuarios.class)    
public class Usuarios implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_usuario")
    private Long idUsuario;



    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    private String login;


    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    private String nome;


    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 15)
    private String senha;


    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="E-mail inválido")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Size(max = 50)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "recebe_novidades")
    private Integer recebeNovidades;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id_entidade_ultimo_acesso")
    private long idEntidadeUltimoAcesso;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id_ultimo_sistema_acesso")
    private long idUltimoSistemaAcesso;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "dt_ultimo_acesso")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dtUltimoAcesso;

    @Column(name = "foto_usuario")
    private BigInteger fotoUsuario;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "flag_administrador")
    private int flagAdministrador;



    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "usuarios")
    private Collection<PermissoesPaginas> permissoesPaginasCollection;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "usuarios")
    private Collection<EntidadesAdministradores> entidadesAdministradoresCollection;


    public Collection<PermissoesPaginas> getPermissoesPaginasCollection() {
        return permissoesPaginasCollection;
    }

    public void setPermissoesPaginasCollection(Collection<PermissoesPaginas> permissoesPaginasCollection) {
        this.permissoesPaginasCollection = permissoesPaginasCollection;
    }

    public Collection<EntidadesAdministradores> getEntidadesAdministradoresCollection() {
        return entidadesAdministradoresCollection;
    }

    public void setEntidadesAdministradoresCollection(
            Collection<EntidadesAdministradores> entidadesAdministradoresCollection) {
        this.entidadesAdministradoresCollection = entidadesAdministradoresCollection;
    }

    public Usuarios() {
    }

   }
```

Comment: `glb` é um _schema_? Adiciona também a DDL de `entidades_administradores`. Possivelmente nela não tenha o campo, mas `Usuarios` deve esperá-lo.

Comment: Sim..glb é um schema

Comment: Adiciona por favor a DDL de `entidades_administradores` e o código de `Usuarios`, seria possível?

Comment: Leva a mal não, mas não vejo nenhum asterisco nas colunas, e a coluna de data não está explícita na consulta

Comment: Sem ter o código da classe `Usuarios` fica difícil responder a esta pergunta.

Comment: @VictorStafusa editei a pergunta e coloquei a classe usuário

Comment: Eu já dei uma resposta, mas só para ter certeza, como é que está o código das classes `PermissoesPaginas` e `EntidadesAdministradores`?

Comment: @VictorStafusa simmm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sua *query* tem os seguintes campos no `ResultSet` (que é o objeto que representa os resultados obtidos da execução da *query*): `id_entidade`, `id_sistema`, `id_pagina`, `id_usuario`, `flag_consultar`, `flag_inserir`, `flag_editar`, `flag_excluir`, `flag_imprimir`.

Já a sua entidade `Usuarios` está mapeada com os seguintes campos: `id_usuario`, `login`, `nome`, `senha`, `email`, `recebe_novidades`, `id_entidade_ultimo_acesso`, `id_ultimo_sistema_acesso`, `dt_ultimo_acesso`, `foto_usuario`, `flag_administrador`.

Observe que o conjunto de campos listados é bem diferente. De fato, o único campo em comum entre as duas listas é o `id_usuario`. Entretanto, você colocou essa *query* em uma anotação de um método que retorna `Collection<Usuarios>`. Ou seja, o Hibernate vai esperar que ao executar essa *query*, em cada linha do `ResultSet` vai haver um registro cujo os campos possam ser usados para construir-se uma instância de `Usuarios`.

O processo utilizado para construir-se uma instância de alguma entidade (no seu caso `Usuarios`) a partir de uma linha do `ResultSet` é feita ao corresponder-se os nomes das colunas do `ResultSet` com os nomes das colunas mapeadas na entidade. Ou seja, um campo `xpto` do `ResultSet` corresponde ao campo `xpto` da entidade. Um campo `abc` do `ResultSet` corresponde ao campo `abc` da entidade, e assim por diante.

Entretanto, como os campos da *query* não coincidem com os campos mapeados na entidade, o Hibernate não consegue saber como converter linhas do `ResultSet` em entidades do tipo `Usuario`, e por isso ele dá esse erro. O erro ocorre no campo `dt_ultimo_acesso` apenas porque esse é o primeiro campo que o Hibernate tentou ler do `ResultSet`, mas o erro poderia ocorrer em qualquer campo.

Não dá para se saber exatamente qual é a solução do seu problema, mas deve ser uma dessas:

- A *query* está certa, mas o tipo de retorno do método está errado. O tipo de retorno seria uma `Collection` de alguma outra coisa que não seja `Usuarios`. Um palpite que tenho é que talvez deveria ser `Collection<PermissoesPaginas>`.
- A *query* está errada, mas o tipo de retorno está correto. Neste caso, você tem que arrumar a *query* para ela trazer os mesmos campos que estão mapeados para `Usuarios`.
- Tanto a *query* quanto o tipo de retorno estão errados.